# Enable Bitcoin payment for a new SaaS

Tags: wallet, receiving, payment-processors

I'd like to create a Software as a Service (written in Python, so it would be nice to have good for this language) with some paid content in BTC.

Basically, I would like that users are able to pay:

- Directly in BTC. I have identified Coinbase and Bitpay, but I would
  also consider using a wallet on my own (in this case, I will use
  bitcoinlib).
- Through a "broker" with PayPal, Visa, etc. and I receive BTC.

I am interested to know your experiences/opinions and if you can give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look no further than [BTCPayServer](https://btcpayserver.org/) - "a self-hosted, open-source cryptocurrency payment processor. It's secure, private, censorship-resistant and free."

The description above taken from their website is absolutely spot on. BTCPayServer allows you to easily accept payments for free, and without an intermediary (unlike Coinbase, BitPay, paypal etc - don't use these, there's absoluteley zero need to pay their exorbitant fees!). It's a fantastic project built and funded by a whole host of awesome bitcoin devs and contributors.

There's a number of very easy [deploy options](https://docs.btcpayserver.org/Deployment/) and plugins (e.g. WooCommerce and Wordpress).

Comment: Thank you so much! I just read the documentation and this is even better than what I had in mind...